Requirements for enabling DNSSEC in Split-Brain Bind9 DNS under a child zone?
I have a fairly complicated split-brain DNS setup, and I'm hoping to add DNSSEC to the ecosystem to support SSHFP (which requires DNSSEC).  I am not totally sure I understand how this needs to work, and need some specific help as to what happens to complete the chain of trust.
I have a hosted domain, "example.com".  The registrar supports DNSSEC and it is enabled.  I have multiple subdomains that branch off of that which are hosted inside my network.  Externally, I need the public IP of my network, and internally, I need a private IP.  My internal network is a domain, specifically "domain.example.com".  I have an A record for "domain.example.com" pointing to the public IP of my network at the registrar.
Inside the network, I have an internal-only bind9 DNS server.  It is authoritative for the zones it serves; for example, "zabbix.domain.com" resolves the internal IP of the web proxy in the network, but externally it resolves the public IP of the network (which hits the web proxy).  I know these will never fully achieve DNSSEC without a huge effort, and that's fine for now.)  Separately, I have lots of servers at "server.domain.example.com" and I want to create SSHFP records for these, and the Bind9 server should be authoritative for domain.example.com.
I have DNSSEC enabled on the zone and get the DNSKEY value back using dig/delv, but ultimately DNSSEC validation fails due to a broken chain of trust.  This is, as I understand it, because there needs to be a DS record on the registrar side for domain.example.com as a complement to the DNSKEY values for my internal resolver's domain.example.com zone.  My registrar does NOT allow me to update that record self-service, but I can submit a ticket to have them do it, and I want to make sure I'm asking for the right things.
I've done research into whether or not I need to add trust anchors to my internal zone, but my understanding is I do not.  Below is the output of (sensitive bits removed) some commands to test:
dig @10.##.##.## domain.example.com DNSKEY +dnssec +multi

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> @10.##.##.## domain.example.com DNSKEY +dnssec +multi
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 24783
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags: do; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 7e8e8e3927e50bbb0100000066d8e4242a8bbf513c31dcd6 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain.example.com.    IN DNSKEY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.example.com. 3600 IN DNSKEY 257 3 13 (
                qwertyuiop==
                ) ; KSK; alg = ECDSAP256SHA256 ; key id = 51820
domain.example.com. 3600 IN DNSKEY 257 3 13 (
                qwertyuiop==
                ) ; KSK; alg = ECDSAP256SHA256 ; key id = 18461
domain.example.com. 3600 IN RRSIG DNSKEY 13 3 3600 (
                20240917225048 20240903215048 18461 domain.example.com.
                qwertyuiop== )
domain.example.com. 3600 IN RRSIG DNSKEY 13 3 3600 (
                20240917225048 20240903215048 51820 domain.example.com.
                qwertyuiop== )

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.##.##.###53(10.##.##.##) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 04 15:50:12 PDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 463


delv @10.##.##.## domain.example.com. A +rtrace

;; fetch: domain.example.com/A
;; fetch: domain.example.com/DNSKEY
;; fetch: domain.example.com/DS
;; fetch: example.com/DNSKEY
;; fetch: example.com/DS
;; fetch: com/DNSKEY
;; fetch: com/DS
;; fetch: ./DNSKEY
;; insecurity proof failed resolving 'domain.example.com/DNSKEY/IN': 10.##.##.###53
;; broken trust chain resolving 'domain.example.com/A/IN': 10.##.##.###53
;; resolution failed: broken trust chain


Don't use different IP for a single domain name. That's wrong by design. Instead use "public" IP, aka global IP also for your "internal" network and just route it internally. If you don't have enough free global IPv4, use global IPv6.

I can't do that because my network doesn't have a static IP; I would need to update the rule every time the IP changes (which is sadly several times a month).  This setup is based on essentially using my hosted DNS as a dynamic DNS.  That's a secondary problem though, the primary issue is DNSSEC on the child internal domain, which I believe needs to validate against the hosted domain if I understand it correctly?

Actually, I have an opnsense firewall and was researching this, and they recommend split DNS over doing this with routes: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/nat/reflection.html

When I would have ever the task to build a new "local" network, I would use global IPv6 for every computer and would use just several firewalls and maybe proxy servers between the different network segments. No routing needed. No split DNS needed. No problems, you just need to rethink networking and stop using IPv4 at all. Maybe use IPv4 for some servers, like your DNS or web servers, but usually IPv4 is no more needed at all.
